# Show download link when uploading files with php and make documents force download

Tags: php, css

I found this tutorial on internet on how to create an upload form with php. Though it is pretty good and well explained, I need to add some additional features, and that is why I need your help.

```
    <?php
require 'config.php';

if (isset ( $_SERVER ['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) == 'POST') {
 // when submit button is clicked
 if (isset ( $_POST ['submit'] )) {
  // get user's data
  $name = $_POST ['name'];
  $email = $_POST ['email'];
  $images = "";

  // check if user has added images
  if(strlen(($_FILES ['upload'] ['tmp_name'] [0])) != 0){
   $upload_dir = "images/";

   // move all uploaded images in directory
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
    $ext = substr(strrchr($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i], "."), 1);

    // generate a random new file name to avoid name conflict
    $fPath = md5(rand() * time()) . ".$ext";
    $images .= $fPath.";";

    $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i], $upload_dir . $fPath);
   } 
  }else {
   // if user doesn't have any images, add default value
   $images .= "no images";
  }

  // write the user's data in database
  // prepare the query
  $query = "INSERT INTO users(name, email,images) VALUES
  ('$name', '$email','$images')";

  // TODO check if the user's informations are successfully added
  // in the database
  $result = mysql_query ( $query ); 
 }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <title>Upload File/s</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- form container -->
 <div id="form">
  <form action="" name="form1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="name" />
   <input name="email" type="email" id="email" value="example@test.com" />
   <div class="upload">
          <input type="file" name="upload[]" id="upload" multiple/>
      </div>
   <Button id="save" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Upload and Save</Button>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When the file is uploaded, the download link is not shown and the file has a random name when uploaded. What i want now is to show the download link and make the files (pdf, png, jpg and other image types) to force download, not to display on another tab. If it is possible too, I would like if the file would keep the same file name when uploaded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you said it is well explained. Look at //generate a new random file name ...

Answer (score 0):

Your script saves the urls to download in the $image variable. At first make the image variable globally:

```
<?php
$images="";
//rest
```

Now you can access it everywhere. So you can echo it inside of your html

```
<div id="response">
<?php
//get every single image in an array
$img=explode(";",$images);
if($img[0]=="no images"){
echo "no uploads yet";
}else{
echo "<a href='images/". $img[1]."' download>Download</a>";
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Outside the </form>

Comment: This is what it looks like when the file is uploaded, can you make it show only an instance of "Download"? https://gyazo.com/325c38e707307c7a67a52c8b4294c364

Comment: At first: ive added a better "no upload" handling and the download should work now too (ive added "download" to the link).

Comment: the image files do not download, they just show up on another tab. How do i make it force download?

Comment: So you want one download button that downloads all?

Comment: I want just a download button that downloads the last uploaded file.

Comment: and there is still a "Download" instance that aims to /images

Comment: Ok but what if you upload multiple files?

Comment: Can you change the upload form to only upload a single file and not multiple files? Sorry I am asking too much but I do not have much knowledge on web programming.

Comment: Just remove the "multiple"

Comment: my website is inaccessible after adding the last code.

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault. Edited :)

Comment: and the download link does not show when i attempt to upload another file.